# How to I switch my sinatra server between development and testing?

Tags: testing, sinatra

I have a sinatra server, and according to the gemfile, there are different groups of gems. Specifically, there is an application group, a testing group, and a development group.  How do I switch my application between these three groups? Specifically, I want to be running my server in testing mode so I can do TDD.

Here is the gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-contrib', require: %w(sinatra/config_file)
gem 'thin'
gem 'slim'
gem 'sinatra-assetpack'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
gem 'compass'

group :application do
  # Here should be all the specifics for the application
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'coveralls'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rubocop'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rake'
  gem 'guard', '2.2.3'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-rubocop'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'guard-shotgun', git: 'git@github.com:rchampourlier/guard-shotgun.git', branch: 'master'
  gem 'blam'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gem Groups**

Bundler installs by default everything. What you probably want is something like this:

```
$ bundle install --without test development
```

for your productive server, this install everything except the test & development group.

source: http://bundler.io/v1.3/groups.html

**Sinatra Environment**

Since you mentions sinatra explicit you maybe also interested in the sinatra config blocks

```
# run only in development environment
configure :development do
  use Rack::Session::Pool, :key => '', :expire_after => 60 * 10
end

# run only in test environment
configure :test do
  use Rack::Session::Pool, :key => 'session', :expire_after => 60 * 60
end

# run everytime
configure do
  MongoMapper.database = 'food'
  User.ensure_index(:username)
  Product.ensure_index(:rnd)
end
```

You can set the different environments with RACK_ENV.

example:

```
RACK_ENV=test ruby mytest.rb
```

source: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#built-in-settings